# Orika Mapping: Concat of two elements to one

Tags: java, dictionary, orika

I need to do something that looks like a simple mapping but I still can't manage how to do it.
What I need to do is to map firstName + lastName on the first class to name on the second one.

Something like this:

```
class Person {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
}

class PrintablePerson {
    String name; // name should be firstName+" "+(lastName)
}
```

Wich is the best way to accomplish this?

**UPDATE:**

I already solved this by implementing my own Mapper by doing this:

```
public class MyCustomMapper extends CustomMapper<Person, PrintablePerson> {
    @Override   
    public void mapAtoB(Person person, PrintablePerson printablePerson, MappingContext context) {
         printablePerson.setName(person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName());
   }
}
```

Then i called the mapper in the customize method by using:

```
mapperFactory.classMap(Person.class, PrintablePerson.class)
.byDefault()
.customize(
     new MyCustomMapper()
 ).register();
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at [Customizing individual ClassMaps](http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/advanced-mappings.html)

```
mapperFactory.classMap(Person.class, PrintablePerson.class)
.byDefault()
.customize(
   new CustomMapper<Person, PrintablePerson>() {
      public void mapAtoB(Person a, PrintablePerson b, MappingContext context) {
         // add your custom mapping code here
         b.setName(a.getFirstName() + " " + a.getLastName());
      }
   })
.register();
```

Comment: This is not working, customize is deprecated and you're instantiating an abstract class (CustomMapper)

Comment: In fact there is two customize methods one is deprecated and replaced by another one.

Yes of course CustomMapper is an abstract class but you can instantiate it with providing an inner implementation, this is a common Java practic.

the inline implementation of the methods mean that Java instantiates an anonymous class which extends the abstract class (or implements the interface). This anonymous class is a concrete class.

Comment: Still not working, i don't know why is taking the deprecated method and the IDE is complaining about abstract class instantiation. Any ideas?